# Internet Explorer - losing HttpSessionState

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have an intranet website. Within this is some code which stores a few variables within an `HttpSessionState` object. For all but one user this works. However for reasons unknown, on this one person's machine, it doesn't appear to be saving it.

The reason I know this is that basically its an asp.net wizard. On step 1 the user makes a selection and that gets stored. When attempting to move to the next step, the session gets checked for a valid value. In this case, the user is making the selection but it never gets remembered.

Very odd as it should be a standard build. I also see the same problem whether IE or Chrome.

Any high level things I could check to help diagnose?

Thanks.

Comment: Is a valid value an empty string? In the asp.net code behind append a zero length string to null form values eg... selection=form[element] +'' or change the client side selection list option elements with <option value="none"></option> (a non-zero length string)

Answer (score 0):

If they have their browser privacy settings set to a high level this could prevent the session cookie from being accepted. Just a stab in the dark.